# Problemas para generar horarios

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un problema, quiero crear un horario por cada curso. Puedo hacer que me aparezcan las asignaturas de cada curso para asignarlas a cada hora. El problema es que cuando guardo los datos solo se me guardan los primeros 12 datos de los 40.

Ya revisé el código y está bien.  Cambié los `select` por `input` para escribir directamente, y sí se guardo entonces.

Creo yo que es porque hay muchos `select` y a cada uno le hice la conexión para que aparezcan las asignaturas. Por esa razón no puse todo el código.

Yo no se tanto de programación por eso lo hice de esa manera porque era la única que sabia.

Si pueden ayudarme resolviendo ese problema o si hay otra forma de realizarlo se los agradecería muchísimo.

```
<?php   
    include "dbcon.php";
    if(isset($_POST['save_multiple_data']))
    {
        $alert='';
            $descripcion         = $_POST['descripcion'];       
            $DAY                 = $_POST['DAY'];
             $initime             = $_POST['initime'];
             $endtime             = $_POST['endtime'];
            foreach($descripcion as $index => $descripcions)
               {
                        $s_descripcion         = $descripcions;
                        $s_DAY                 = $DAY[$index];
                        $s_initime             = $initime[$index];
                        $s_endtime             = $endtime[$index];
                        $query_insert = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO horario_clases (descripcion,DAY,initime,endtime) VALUES ('$s_descripcion','$s_DAY','$s_initime','$s_endtime')");
                       // $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query_insert);
                   }
                if($query_insert){
                    $alert='<p class="msg_save">Horario creado correctamente.</p>';
                }else{
                    $alert='<p class="msg_error">Error al crear el horario.</p>';
                }}
    //Mostrar Datos
    if(empty($_REQUEST['id']))
    {
        header('Location: lista_curso.php');
    }
    $id_curso = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $sql= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT *
                                    FROM curso
                                    WHERE id_curso= $id_curso ");
    $result_sql = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if($result_sql == 0){
        header('Location: lista_curso.php');
    }else{
        $option = '';
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            # code...
            $id_curso           = $data['id_curso'];
            $descrip_curso      = $data['descrip_curso'];
            $estado_curso       = $data['estado_curso'];
        }   }?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head><body>
        <section id="container">    
        <div class="form_register2">
            <div class="alert"><?php echo isset($alert) ? $alert : ''; ?></div>
            <div class="titulo4" style="width: 1030px;">
            <h1 style="font-size: 18px;"><i class='fas fa-calendar'></i>  Horario de clases</h1>
            <a style="font-size: 16px;" href="lista_curso_horario.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Volver</a>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post">
<table>
  <caption><strong><?php echo $descrip_curso; ?> curso</strong></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Lunes</th>
      <th>Martes</th>
      <th>Miércoles</th>
      <th>Jueves</th>
      <th>Viernes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>  
       <th>07:15-08:00</th>
       <input type="hidden" name="initime[]" value="07:15:00">
        <input type="hidden" name="endtime[]" value="08:00:00">
        <input type="hidden" name="DAY[]" value="Lunes"> 
      <td>
        <?php
                    $fk_id_curso_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso from asignatura a
                                           INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso
                                           WHERE id_curso= $fk_id_curso_asignatura AND a.estado_asignatura=1
                                           ORDER BY fk_id_curso_asignatura DESC 
                                           ");

                    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                    ?>
                <select name="descripcion[]" required autocomplete="off">
                                <option></option>

                <?php
                if ($result > 0) {
                    while ($asig = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?>"><?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?></option>
                <?php
        
                    }
                }
                ?>          
                </select>
            </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="initime[]" value="07:15:00">
    <input type="hidden" name="endtime[]" value="08:00:00">
    <input type="hidden" name="DAY[]" value="Martes"> 
            <?php
                    $fk_id_curso_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso from asignatura a
                                           INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso
                                           WHERE id_curso= $fk_id_curso_asignatura AND a.estado_asignatura=1
                                           ORDER BY fk_id_curso_asignatura DESC 
                                           ");

                    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                    ?>
                <select name="descripcion[]" required autocomplete="off">
                                <option></option>

                <?php
                if ($result > 0) {
                    while ($asig = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?>"><?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?></option>
                <?php
        
                    }
                }
                ?>          
                </select>
                </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="initime[]" value="07:15:00">
    <input type="hidden" name="endtime[]" value="08:00:00"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="DAY[]" value="Miercoles">
            <?php
                    $fk_id_curso_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso from asignatura a
                                           INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso
                                           WHERE id_curso= $fk_id_curso_asignatura AND a.estado_asignatura=1
                                           ORDER BY fk_id_curso_asignatura DESC 
                                           ");
                    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                    ?>
                <select name="descripcion[]" required autocomplete="off">
                                <option></option>
                <?php
                if ($result > 0) {
                    while ($asig = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?>"><?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }                   }
                ?>          
                </select>
            </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="initime[]" value="07:15:00">
    <input type="hidden" name="endtime[]" value="08:00:00">
    <input type="hidden" name="DAY[]" value="Jueves"> 
            <?php
                    $fk_id_curso_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso from asignatura a
                                           INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso
                                           WHERE id_curso= $fk_id_curso_asignatura AND a.estado_asignatura=1
                                           ORDER BY fk_id_curso_asignatura DESC 
                                           ");

                    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                    ?>
                <select name="descripcion[]" required autocomplete="off">
                                <option></option>
                <?php
                if ($result > 0) {
                    while ($asig = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?>"><?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?></option>
                <?php           
                    }                   }
                ?>          
                </select>
            </td>
      <td>
<input type="hidden" name="initime[]" value="07:15:00">
    <input type="hidden" name="endtime[]" value="08:00:00"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="DAY[]" value="Viernes"> 
            <?php
                    $fk_id_curso_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso from asignatura a
                                           INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso
                                           WHERE id_curso= $fk_id_curso_asignatura AND a.estado_asignatura=1
                                           ORDER BY fk_id_curso_asignatura DESC 
                                           ");

                    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                    ?>
                <select name="descripcion[]" required autocomplete="off">
                                <option></option>
                <?php
                if ($result > 0) {
                    while ($asig = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?>"><?php echo $asig['nombre_asignatura']; ?></option>
                <?php           
                    }
                }
                ?>          
                </select>
            </td>
    </tr>
// Y ASI SUCESIVAMENTE CON LOS DEMAS CAMPOS QUE NO LOS PONGO XQ SE HACE BASTASTANTE     
                </select> 
            </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
            <input type="submit" value="&#128190; Guardar" class="btn_save" name="save_multiple_data">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

PHP tiene un límite de datos para enviar/recibir por formulario, por defecto es 8Mb y podrías estar enviando una cantidad mayor; generalmente, se mostraría una página en blanco porque no se puede procesar, por lo que podría haber algún otro error en tu script y deberías tratar de simplificar:

1. En la tabla `horario_clases` guarda ID de asignatura en vez de la descripción o nombre.
2. Estás creando una consulta para llenar cada *select* y, definitivamente, no es lo óptimo, porque puedes hacer una sola consulta, guardando la información en un arreglo y usándolo cada que lo necesites; lo mismo para los horarios y días.
3. El código es muy repetitivo y deberías crear funciones para facilitar las cosas.
4. No sé si tengas una forma de ordenar los días, porque los guardas por nombre y no por identificador, eso también podría complicarte la lógica al mostrar horarios.

```
<?php
// Crea un arreglo con los días, no importa que no los uses todos
$days = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
// Crea un arreglo con los horarios disponibles
// Lo ideal, sería tenerlos en otra tabla de tu base de datos
// Cada elemento será otro arreglo [hora inicio, hora fin]
$hours = [
    ['7:15:00', '8:00:00'],
    ['8:00:00', '9:00:00']
];
// Crea un arreglo con las asignaturas
$asignaturas = [];

$fk_id_curso_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso
    FROM asignatura a
    INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso
    WHERE id_curso= $fk_id_curso_asignatura AND a.estado_asignatura=1
    ORDER BY fk_id_curso_asignatura DESC");
// No es necesario contar las filas, solo recorrer para llenar el arreglo
while ($asig = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $asignaturas[] = $asig;
}

// Crea una función para generar los select
function selectAsignatura($asignaturas) {
    $ret = '<select name="descripcion[]" required>';
    $ret .= '<option value="0">-- Selecciona --</select>';
    // Recorre el arreglo para llenar las opciones
    foreach($asignatura as $asig) {
        // El valor debe ser ID de asignatura
        $ret .= "<option value=\"{$asig[id_asignatura]}\">{$asig[nombre_asignatura]}</option>";
    }
    $ret .= '</select>';
    return $ret;
}
```

Ahora, viene la parte *divertida*, crear la tabla usando los arreglos y la función para los *select*, sabiendo que las filas están basadas en horas y las columnas en días:

```
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
  <caption><strong><?php echo $descrip_curso; ?> curso</strong></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <!-- Esto se podría hacer con un ciclo -->
      <th>Lunes</th>
      <th>Martes</th>
      <th>Miércoles</th>
      <th>Jueves</th>
      <th>Viernes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
// Por cada hora habrá una fila
foreach($hours as $hour) {
    // Se crea la fila y celda de hora
    echo "<tr>
        <th>{$hour[1]}</th>";
    // Ahora, se recorren los días para crear cada columna
    // Sabiendo que Lunes está en la posición 1 y Viernes en la 5
    for($dia = 1; $dia < 6; $dia ++) {
        // Crea una variable para el select con la función y el arreglo
        $select = selectAsignatura($asignaturas);
        // Cada columna tendrá los inputs ocultos para hora y día, así como select
        // Por ahora, el día se guarda por nombre
        echo "<td>
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"initime[]\" value=\"{$hour[0]}\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"endtime[]\" value=\"{$hour[1]}\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"DAY[]\" value=\"{$days[$day]}\">
            $select
        </td>";
    }
    // Finalizar la fila
    echo '</tr>';
}

// Finalizar la tabla y formulario
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Como puedes ver, esto reduce mucho el código y un poco los datos a enviar por formulario. Insisto, lo ideal sería que también tengas una tabla para horas, de forma que solo guardes ID y puedes acceder a la descripción cuando consultes la tabla de horarios con *JOIN* a asignaturas y horas.

**Nota importante:** No copies y pegues el código, porque no tengo forma de probarlo. Analízalo y trata de entenderlo, después ya podrás integrarlo en tu proyecto y corregir los posibles errores que se me hayan escapado.